# Drag and drop file upload strange behaviour

Tags: file-upload, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 3.5 and I have ran into a pretty disturbing problem. The component looks like this in the xhtml:

```
<p:tab id="installApp" title="Install application">
        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <p:panel header="Upload status" id="upld_status">
          <p:dataTable id="errorTable" var="error"
           value="#{applicationInstallerBean.uploadMsgs}">

           <p:column headerText="Application">
            <h:outputText value="#{error.filename}" />
           </p:column>

           <p:column headerText="Status">
            <h:outputText value="#{error.errorMsg}" />
           </p:column>

          </p:dataTable>        
        </p:panel>

        <p:remoteCommand name="clearPrevious" update="upld_status uploader" action="#{applicationInstallerBean.clearPrevious}" process="@this" />


        <p:fileUpload id="uploader" multiple="true" dragDropSupport="true" onstart="clearPrevious()"
                fileUploadListener="#{applicationInstallerBean.install}" uploadLabel="Install"
                mode="advanced" update="@this upld_status" auto="false"
                allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(zip)$/" styleClass="install_app_fileupload" />                 

        </h:form>
        <p:panel header="Help" toggleable="true">
            <ui:include src="applicationInstallHelp.xhtml" />
        </p:panel>
    </p:tab>
```

Now the behaviour I'm experiencing is pretty strange:

For the first few times, uploading files with drag'n'drop method works fine. After a few uploads, the following errors appear totally undetermenistic:

- FileUpload component disappears after pressing Upload button, only to reappear when I refresh the page
- the *onstart* method gets called a lot of times during upload
- the table containing the status of the upload does not refresh or only one of the files appear there, when multiple are uploaded
- I also get a message from the browser that a script is running on this page and I can abort or continue

**What I have tried:**

Removing the *h:form* element, since this is an include in the index file, which already has a *h:form* element in it

**Result:** basicly the same, with the difference, that dropping a file for the first time onto the component automatically uploads it, but *auto* is set to false

I have also tried emptying the browser cache, redeploying the application from a scratch, turning off *multiple*...all with no luck.

The files I'm uploading are 80k to 9mb.

From this it looks to me, that uploading too much files makes the whole thing go crazy, but I cannot really think of a solution. Any help would be appreciated.

**Update:** During testing I found that the *onstart* method ALWAYS fires more than once after the first upload. For the first time it only fires once. On the second upload about 7-10 times, on the third time it seems it keeps firing until I end the session. This is pretty strange and I think it may be the root of the problems. Any ideas on this?

Thank you in advance!